How can I figure out how much of the trade between each pair of countries is conducted in USD?
I want to get a measure of (an aspect of) the dominance of the US dollar in international trade - which is something I often hear commentators mention.
Is this available as processed data somewhere? Perhaps by some international body? If not, is there a reasonably-easy way to collect the relevant statistics?
Note: I'm willing to limit myself to a single year and it doesn't have to be the last one necessarily.

I'm not sure it's available like this. All pairs of states is a pretty large number (32,220 or so--mkay just half that if you take them unordered and so just the total trade between a pair, instead of exports & imports separately. But still  a large number.) OTOH you can much more easily find the % of world trade done in dollars. Which for the purposes of your first para is nearly the same thing. Per-pair-of-states info is more relevant if you want to figure out who the outliers are.

When states trade, it usually does not mean that the two national governments trade. The overwhelming majority of international trade is commercial, between non-state actors, most of that between companies. And in turn, most of those transactions are confidential agreements between the companies. I don't see how this could be answered.

On a methodological note, what exactly does it mean for a trade deal to be "conducted in USD"? Is a Forex swap where one of the two currencies is USD "conducted in USD", for instance? Even if two countries would collect this data, if they don't use the same definition you can't compare the outcomes.

@timetakesitstoll: Well, if it were the top 50 trading states that would be pretty good too. Although - 32,220 is not such a huge number, it just means that I need further statistical reduction for something browsable.

I cannot think of any resource where this information can be accessed for every country pair, and I’m not even sure that many countries record such data at that level of precision.
It is common practice, however, to keep track of the currencies used with respect to aggregate exports and imports, at least of goods. For the European Union, the situation is summarised in the graphs shown below, taken from this article. The euro dominates as invoicing currency for exports; the dollar for imports. Although not specified (being included with “Other currencies”) the pound sterling probably comes third for both imports and exports.

Detailed figures for all EU/EEA member states, for the period 2010 to 2023, can be found in this table.
Edit: There is also the paper “Dominant Currency Pricing in International Trade of Services”, which states as its “central finding”:

that the use of the USD as a vehicle currency in international transactions in services is extensive – but systematically lower than in international transactions in goods (by 8 percentage points on average).


For the Nordic region, a group of countries on the margin of the EU (all of them part of the single market, although only three are member states), I can provide the additional information that a significant part of the trade between those countries takes place in local currencies. Iceland, for example, reports that 59% of its exports are invoiced in dollars, 29% in euros, and 5% in each of GBP and NOK, while over 10% of the imports are conducted in DKK and SEK.

Two points I wanted to make with that first comment: (1) other currencies than USD and EUR are sometimes important in regional trading, and (2) even in such cases those two usually dominate.

The Currency Composition of Official Foreign Exchange Reserves (COFER) database keeps an eye on the current volume of the global currencies. This database is maintained by the Statistics Department of the IMF. I found an interesting dashboard here on the IMF website that shows exactly what you are looking for. The dashboard is not just limited to USD but also covers other major international currencies.
To gauge trade conducted by countries worldwide, WTO provides this data rich portal/dashboard. It is difficult to connect the dots with each country's trade with other countries. For that one might be interested to browse the trade ministry website.

That looks like currency reserves, not payments or currency transfers?

I update my answer. Actually, the OP's title and content are asking two different things. I hope the update would help answering both questions now.
